# How can i monitor community edition of Neo4j using JMX?

Tags: neo4j, jmx

I have a one question about Neo4j

Most of the monitoring features are only available in the Enterprise edition of Neo4j.

But I just use Community edition of Neo4j(Ver.2.3.10)

However I think that also Community edition can be monitored by JMX

If it possible, How can I monitor Community edition of Neo4j using JMX?

Answer (score 1):

It is an Enterprise Edition feature only, the Community Edition does not expose any metrics.

Hope this helps,
Tom